# jQuery Div Slider not working?

Tags: jquery

So I'm looking for a jQuery div slider like this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZdCw7IEYdV5YVeGg33oX?p=preview

I have tried  to change the jQuery listed below:

```
<script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However, when I run it, buttons don't work.

Can someone help please?

I'm trying to understand what seems to be going wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: on Chrome I get them working... maybe you already change it?
BTW, if you're not just "playing around" try this: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ I've been using that in several projects and no issues...

Comment: 1) When possible, post your questions by using the Stackoverlow code snippet option and don't link to external sites like plnkr.co, jsfiddle etc... You can see how I did it in my answer. 2) Keep an eye on your console for errors. You would have been able to find it yourself if you had checked it.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add `event` as a parameter to your functions because you get the following errors when `event.preventDefault()` is called:

```
ReferenceError: event is not defined[Learn More]  script.js:11:7
ReferenceError: event is not defined[Learn More]  script.js:4:7
```

change your code like this:

```
$('#right-button').click(function(event) {
  ...
}

$('#left-button').click(function(event) {
  ...
}
```

#### example:

```js
$('#right-button').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#content').animate({
    scrollLeft: "+=200px"
  }, "slow");
});

$('#left-button').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#content').animate({
    scrollLeft: "-=200px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.internal {
  width: 31.75%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.center {
  float: left;
  width: 38.9%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1px;
  overflow: auto;
  /*will change this to hidden later to deny scolling to user*/
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="left">
  left div
  <button id="left-button">
      swipe left
    </button>
</div>
<div class="center" id="content">
  <div class=internal>
    div 1
  </div>
  <div class=internal>
    div 2
  </div>
  <div class=internal>
    div 3
  </div>
  <div class=internal>
    div 4
  </div>
  <div class=internal>
    div 5
  </div>
  <div class=internal>
    div 6
  </div>
  <div class=internal>
    div 7
  </div>
  <div class=internal>
    div 8
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <button id="right-button">
      swipe right
    </button> right div
</div>
```